# Access ZeroTier Network from Internet - Connection refused

Tags: php, curl, vpn, zerotier

We have a ZeroTier VPN network for accessing an API installed in local machine.
When I try to connect using cURL everythings works in localhost, but connection was refused from live server.

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8088/api/person/get/7576?access_token=XXXXXX",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
  CURLOPT_USERAGENT=>'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13'
));

if (curl_exec($curl) === FALSE) {
   die("Curl Failed: " . curl_error($curl));
} else {
   $response = curl_exec($curl);
}

curl_close($curl);
var_dump ($response);
```

This code works with "localhost" but fails with IP number.
cURLs is enabled in the hosting control panel.

Some suggestion???

Comment: *Connection refused* can be because of ssl or wrong credentials

Comment: This has me crazy, I already checked configurations on the server, on the zerotier network, I did tests with 3 different remote servers... I don't know what to do anymore.

Comment: what is actual error ?

Comment: Curl Failed: Failed to connect to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX port 8088: Connection refused